# Order preservation of Kotlin map keys

Tags: kotlin

I have not been able to find any explicitly stated documentation that addresses order preservation for the following case.

```
val map = mapOf(
"k2" to "v1",
"k1" to "v2",
"k3" to "v3" 
)

val keys = map.keys.toList()
```

I would expect keys to always be in the following order:

```
["k2", "k1", "k3"]
```

Is it guaranteed that the order of keys be preserved in the same order they were initialized?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, if you look at implementation of [mapOf](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-of.html), it used LinkedHashMap which from [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) says that it normally preservers key order, unless in case of re-inserting key.

But in case internal implementation might change for some reason I would rather suggest using [linkedMapOf](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/linked-map-of.html) in same way as you did `mapOf`.

`LinkedHashMap` uses [LinkedKeySet](https://runtimeverification.com/monitor/propertydb/java/util/LinkedHashMap.LinkedKeySet.html) implementation when returning `Set` of keys which ensures correct order.